# Do I use DrawerLayout in activity_main.xml when using fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I am building an app with android jetpack navigation and fragments. I would like to include a navigation drawer in my app but I am unsure about where exactly I would put my DrawerLayout tag. I want the nav drawer to be accessible from most (but not all) fragments. Do I put this tag in activity_main.xml or in every layout file that I would like to include a nav drawer in? Thank you!

Comment: take in activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `activity_main.xml` wrap your main layout with `DrawerLayout`. Since you want it to be accessible from anywhere then you don't need to add `addOnDestinationChangedListener` on navController. But if you don't want on specific fragment then you have to add it and put condition to check that NavDestination and lock it as below

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { nc: NavController, nd: NavDestination, _: Bundle? ->
    if (nd.id == nc.graph.startDestination) {
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
    } else {
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!